# Several questions about constructors of std::bitset?

Tags: c++, string, bitset

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

#### #3

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >

explicit bitset( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& str,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type pos = 0,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type n =
                     std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::npos);                                                    (until C++11)
```

---

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >

explicit bitset( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& str,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type pos = 0,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type n =
                     std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::npos,
                 CharT zero = CharT('0'),
                 CharT one = CharT('1'));                                                                                             (since C++11)
template< class CharT >
```

#### #4

```
explicit bitset( const CharT* str,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT>::size_type n =
                     std::basic_string<CharT>::npos,
                 CharT zero = CharT('0'),
                 CharT one = CharT('1'));                                                                                            (since C++11)
```

I have several questions about it:

1. For `#3` and `#4`, why the standard specifies `std::basic_string<...>` instead of just `std::string`? I know `std::string` is also known as  `std::basic_string<char>` and other character types like `wchar_t`, `char16_t` can be applied to `std::basic_string<...>`. But I think it is not necessary because `bitset` contains `0` and `1`, just as its name indicates.
2. Honestly, I'm not very familiar with `string` class: why `#4` is added? What can `const CharT*`  do, which cannot be achieved with `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>`?

Comment: One question per question please!

Comment: Sorry for frequent editing, but I found another grammatical error: "What is ```const charT*``` can do" should be corrected as "What can ```const charT*``` do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#3 is convenient for people who work with wide characters--you can't expect people to convert their strings of wide "0"s and "1"s to narrow strings to use a string-based constructor just because you happen to know the values are always binary--otherwise this constructor should be replaced by a 1-bit-wide string variant.  In other words, it is more convenient as written, so what's the advantage of taking away that convenience?

#4 is for people who have a string literal or pointer-to-char-array so that they need not construct a useless temporary std::string.